# Locked out of Active directory After Joining Domain Through VPN

Tags: active-directory, windows-10

Usually , if I join a domain locally in the office , then it will cache credentials  and allow a remote user to log into their machine when away from the local doman.

I have joined a domain through the VPN ( Open VPN  ) , but when I restarted the computer , I am locked out of Active directory.

"We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected yo your organisations network and try again.  If you previously signed in on this device with another credential , you can sign in with that credential"

I have forgotten the local admin password ( still trying ) , and can't log in using previous credential because it was on a different domain

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Short of breaking in to the PC or re-establishing your connection to the domain network, there is nothing you can do.

This sounds like a procedure you perform regularly. In the future, make sure you test a local account as part of that procedure.